# Por que um nativo de português consegue "vibrar o R" e um estadunidense não, sendo que ambos apenas têm o "tap"?

Tags: diferenças, fonologia

No Brasil e em Portugal, a maioria das pessoas tem dois modos de falar < r > em português. O primeiro é como em “caro”, que é o “tap” (/ɾ/); o segundo, como em “carro”, que é /h/. No inglês estadunidense, há tanto o “tap” (/ɾ/), como em “*wa**t**er*”, quanto /h/, como em “***h**i*”. O /ɾ/ em inglês “substitui” o < d > ou < t > quando um desses está entre vogais, como em “*ge**tt**ing*”.

Porém, nunca vi um nativo de português ter problema em falar o R vibrado (/r/), como em espanhol “*pe**rr**o*”; ou mesmo em distingüir “*pero*” (/ɾ/) de “perro” (/r/) falando ou ouvindo, apenas precisando dum pouco de treino. Também, às vezes, vê-se alguém usando /r/ em “burro”, por exemplo. Mas não é tão comum ver um americano conseguindo falar /r/ em “*perro*” facilmente ou até mesmo /ɾ/ em “caro”, ao menos que já tenha treinado.

O inglês lá não distingüe /d/ e /t/ de /ɾ/, o que influencia, mas, mesmo assim, acho curioso ver tanta dificuldade em falar o /ɾ/ em “cara”, sendo que têm o /ɾ/.

Então, pergunto: por que isso acontece?

Observação: letras entre barras (ex.: “/a/”) representam um som. Pelo que sei, não é necessário usar o [Alfabeto Fonético Internacional (AFI)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfabeto_Fon%C3%A9tico_Internacional) para isso, até porque muitos não o fazem, mas optei por usá-lo. Então, é fácil de alguém pesquisar pelo som.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116138/discussion-on-question-by-schilive-por-que-um-nativo-de-portugues-consegue-virb).